# Use PHPUnit on PhpStorm IDE

Tags: php, phpunit, mamp, phpstorm

I've developed a simple test class usign PHPUnit on my PhpStorm IDE.

- PHP version: 5.4.25
- PHPUnit version 4.2.1
- MAMP 3.0.2
- PHPStorm 7.1

This is the configuration of my IDE:

[image]

[image]

And this is my Test class:

```
namespace test\controllers;


class AuthTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected function setUp() {
        parent::setUp(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        echo "start";
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        echo "end";
    }


    public function testProva() {
        $tot = 5;

        $this->assertEquals($tot, 5);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the configuration of my test run:

[image]

When I Run the class (class name: AuthTest, file name: AuthTest.php) I obtain the following error: `Process finished with exit code 255`
But when I run the same class by command line `phpunit path/test/folder/` it works fine.

What is wrong?

Comment: *"PHPUnit version 5.2.1"* -- Welcome in 21014 time traveller. 4.2 is the latest version of PHPUnit ATM. In any case: the info you have provided is not enough: 1) What PhpStorm version do you use? 2) What command PhpStorm uses to execute PHPUnit tests (show screenshot -- make sure that it shows FULL command -- use line warapping option for that); 3) File name where this test case is located (just file name).

Comment: @LazyOne I've updated my question, I hope I've given you all necessary information. Where can I find what command PhpStorm uses to execute PHPUnit test? I added a screenshot with my test run configuration, is what you needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PhpStorm v7.x does not support PhpUnit 4.x (only 3.6 ..or maybe 3.7 MAX)**.

*PhpStorm uses special helper/wrapper script for integration purposes (so that IDE receives test progress/results in understandable format (much-much easier that parsing PHPUnit native output, which does not provide much details needed for IDE)). This wrapper in PhpStorm v7.x does not support PHPUnit v4.x.*

For PhpUnit 4.x support you should try [v8 EAP build](http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm) (or wait for v8 official release -- 1-2 months from now, approximately).